# How to check if a string contains any options in a group of words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to check if 'string' contains "ring" or "qwer" or "qwwe". I would like it to be an `if statement` but I don't know how to achieve this and all I see on Google is `foreach`, which I am not sure will be applicable in my case.

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
 var groupofwords = "ring","qwer","qwwe";
   if(/*string contains ATLEAST ONE of the words in groupofwords*/){
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "Hurray, the word string contains either 'ring','qwer','qwwe'";
    }else{
      document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "the word string does not contain either 'ring','qwer','qwwe'";
     }
```

I also saw something like this:

```
var map = {
'ring','qwer','qwwe'/*this isn't actually what i saw, but what i can recall*/
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the words you want to check in an array and use `.some` to check if a particular word contains any of those words.

```js
const groupofwords = ["ring","qwer","qwwe"];
let word = "qwerty";
if(groupofwords.some(w=>word.includes(w))){
  console.log(word, "yes");
} else {
  console.log(word, "no");
}
word = "qwety";
if(groupofwords.some(w=>word.includes(w))){
  console.log(word, "yes");
} else {
  console.log(word, "no");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do that

```js
var txtElement = document.querySelector("input"),
  feedbackElement = document.querySelector("p"),
  words = ["ring", "qwer", "qwwe"];

txtElement.oninput = function() {
  for(var i = 0;i < words.length; i++) {
    if(txtElement.value.includes(words[i])) {
      feedbackElement.innerHTML = "Hurray, the word string contains either 'ring','qwer','qwwe'";
      return;
    }
  }
  feedbackElement.innerHTML = "the word string does not contain either 'ring','qwer','qwwe'";
}
```

```css
.input {
  width: 100px;
}
#hidden-text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#hidden-text, .input {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Serif;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="type a word">
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using RegEx :

```
var groupofwords =   ["ring","qwer","qwwe"];

var str = " your text to be matched..... ";

if (new RegExp(groupofwords.join("|")).test(str) {
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "Hurray the word string 
                                     contains either 'ring','qwer','qwwe'";
 }
else {
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "the string does not contain 
                                     either 'ring','qwer','qwwe'";
}
```